# Is $ (-1)^n(x-a)^n = (a-x)^n?$ If not, why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I came across this during an attempt at a Taylor series expansion (which I'm not very good at yet), and assumed this would be true because $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$. Plugged it into Wolfram Alpha, though, and it returns false. Can't figure out why this might be.

Comment: Yes. Try expanding with the binomial theorem.

Comment: Yes, $a^nb^n = (ab)^n$ and $(-1)(x-a)=a-x$.

Comment: Wolfram is probably assuming $n$ is potentially complex, in which case it gets trickier - it is not true in general that $a^nb^n=(ab)^n$ if $n$ is complex.

Comment: Why would Wolfram Alpha tell me otherwise, though? I've never seen it be wrong before: I fed in "is ((-1)^n)*((x-a)^n) equal to (a-x)^n" and got false, and it appeared to be interpreted correctly. Edit: Didn't see your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

$$(a-x)^n = ((-1) \cdot (x-a))^n = (-1)^n(x-a)^n$$

where the last equality follows from the rule $(ab)^n = a^n b^n$ which you specified.

(Assuming $n \in \Bbb Z$, otherwise the above is not true because $(-1)^n$ might be complex.)

Comment: What is $(-1)^{\sqrt{2}}$? You need $n\in\mathbb Z$ to assert this, really.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Hmm.. agreed. Thank you.

Comment: @naslundx Where are you getting $$(-(a-x))^n = ((-1) \cdot (x-a))^n $$ from?  I don't see how you can switch x and a without removing the negative out in front.  I think I see that you're trying to say that pulling a negative out will flip x and a, but it shouldn't it be flipped in the first part as well then?  I say that because to me the following equation you wrote is false even though you may just be representing a "partial step" in which you show yourself pulling out a negative: $$(a-x)^n =(-(a-x))^n$$

Comment: @user3330644 Sorry, I wrote that one wrong. It's correct now.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram is probably assuming $n$ is potentially complex, in which case it gets trickier - it is not true in general that $a^nb^n=(ab)^n$ if $n$ is complex. Indeed, it is already problematic with $n$ rational, say.